# React Native how to count the length of charater for a text?

Tags: react-native

I have customized a "Read More" component for showing text.

The idea is when the text is more than 2 lines, will appear "Read more " and collapse the rest of the content. When click the "Read more ",you will be able to see all the content and appear "Read Less" attention.

I was so happy that it works until I found an issue which is when the text has less one sentence ,it  will still appear the "Read More" attention, which doesn't make sense .. I had no idea how to solve this problem ...Could you please take a look of my code, thank you so much !

"Read more" component:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import colors from '../config/colors';

function ReadMore({txt_content,num_lines}) {
        const [read,setRead] =useState(false);
        const[text,setText] = useState(num_lines);
        const[read_less,set_read_less] =useState(false);
        
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           <Text
           style={styles.txt}
           numberOfLines = {text}
           >{txt_content}</Text>


           <View style={styles.read_container}>
           {!read&&<Text style={styles.read_more}onPress = {()=>{setText(null);setRead(true);set_read_less(true)}}>Read More</Text> } 
          {read_less&&<Text style={styles.read_more}onPress = {()=>{setText(2);set_read_less(false);setRead(false)}}>Read Less</Text>}
           </View>
          
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex : 1,

    },
    read_container : {
        flex :1,
        alignItems : 'center',
        padding : 5,
        
    },
    txt : {
        fontSize : 16,
        color : colors.medium,
        textAlign : 'center',
    },
    read_more : {
        color : colors.primary,
        fontSize : 16,
    },
})
export default ReadMore;
```

It would be awesome that if the `txt_content.length` is less than 14, neither the "Read more" or "Read Less" label would appears ... But I don't know how to make it work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set your value to state as an empty string.
2. Within your initial View, create a TextInput field.
3. Apply the required props
4. Apply the “onChangeText” prop.
5. Create a “Text” field TextInput and have it count the length of your
   value.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
export default class CharacterCounter extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    value:''
    };
  }
render(){
   return(
      <View>
        
         <TextInput
            multiline = {true}
            numberOfLines = {6}
            maxLength = {130}
            placeholder='I am Jahnavi Sananse'
            value={this.state.value}
            onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({value})}
              
            />
      
          
         <Text>
            Characters Left:{this.state.value.length}/130
         </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jahnavi Sananse,

Comment: Hi Yellow Clock!

Comment: Hi Jahnavi Sananse,Sorry that I didn't complete the sentence well XD .. I was wanted to say ,hmm ,you have a great idea ,however ,in my case ,it can't use TextInput ..The reason is : it is a component just to show the text .It don't receive any input from the user . someplace will need to show just one sentence ,some place may need to show two sences .that's why I want to make it more flexable ,when it has more than 14 characters ,don't show "read more". Do you have more idea about it ?Thank you so much again .

Comment: My Pleasure @Yellow Clock and I'm Sorry I don't have any idea about "read more".

Answer (score 1):

With the tip of Jahnavi Sananse ,I have finally have a solution :

```
   import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import colors from '../config/colors';


function ReadMore({txt_content="",num_lines}) {
        const [read,setRead] =useState(false);
        const[text,setText] = useState(num_lines);
        const[read_less,set_read_less] =useState(false); 
        const num_txt = txt_content.length;
   
           
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           <Text
           style={styles.txt}
           numberOfLines = {text}
           >{txt_content}</Text>

       {(num_txt>=70)&&(
         <View style={styles.read_container}>
         {!read&&<Text style={styles.read_more}onPress = {()=>{setText(null);setRead(true);set_read_less(true)}}>Read More</Text> } 
        {read_less&&<Text style={styles.read_more}onPress = {()=>{setText(2);set_read_less(false);setRead(false)}}>Read Less</Text>}
         </View>  
       )}   
       


         
           
          
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex : 1,

    },
    read_container : {
        flex :1,
        alignItems : 'center',
        padding : 5,
        
    },
    txt : {
        fontSize : 16,
        color : colors.medium,
        textAlign : 'center',
    },
    read_more : {
        color : colors.primary,
        fontSize : 16,
    },
})
export default ReadMore;
```

Comment: Thanks to you !! Without your tip ,I can't solve the problem .You have done a good job !!

Comment: That's my pleasure!